# Symfony form creates new object and create first one-to-many object

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity for support tickets: SupportTicket(). I also have an entry for replies to each ticket: SupportEntry(). I setup a one-to-many relationship between SupportTicket() and SupportEntry().

Now what I'm trying to do is build my form so that it creates the initial SupportTicket and then inserts the first SupportEntry, all in the same form. I've been messing around with my code for a while, only half-understanding what I'm doing, but this is where I'm at right now:

```
// My controller, creating the form
$supportTicket = new SupportTicket();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($supportTicket)
        ->add('subject', 'text', array(
            'label'         => 'Subject'
        ))
        ->add('jobNumber', 'text', array(
            'label'         => 'Job Number'
        ))
        ->add('supportGroup', 'entity', array(
            'label'         => 'Group',
            'class'         => 'ShawmutClientBundle:SupportGroup',
            'property' =>   'name',
            'multiple'      => true,
            'expanded'      => true
        ))
       // ->add('supportEntries', new SupportEntryType())
        ->add('supportEntries', new SupportEntryType())

        ->add('Save', 'submit')

        ->getForm();
```

My attempt at the custom form type

```
<?php
namespace Shawmut\ClientBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SupportEntryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder->add('comment', 'textarea');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Shawmut\ClientBundle\Entity\SupportEntry',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'SupportEntryType';
}
}
```

The form does have the comment box that I've pulled in from the form type, but when I try to submit the form, I get this error:

> Neither the property "supportEntries" nor one of the methods "setSupportEntries()",     "_*set()" or "*_call()" exist and have public access in class "Me\MyBundle\Entity\SupportTicket".

And yeah, that makes sense. It should be the addSupportEntries() method which is there. So how do I tell the form builder to use addSupportEntries instead of setSupportEntries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty sure using a collection will do the job.  ->add('supportEntries', 'collection', array('type' => new SupportEntryType()))  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the way to go but I can't figure out how to render the textarea. It seems to go into the template if I include the allow_add and protype as true, but then I have to render the field using Javascript. Then, it doesn't pass along the value properly in the form. Kinda stuck at the moment.

Comment: Add a SupportEntry to your SupportTicket so the form system has something to work against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `collection` form type a go.

```
->add(
    'supportEntries',
    'collection',
    array(
        'type' => new SupportEntryType(),
        'label' => 'Support Entries',
        'error_bubbling' => true,
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still not working. The problem is that the collection includes the label but the "comment" textarea in my SupportEntryType is not displaying. Trying to submit the form shows that the value for the textarea can't be blank, so it looks like the form is correct but the textarea isn't showing up. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: The problem appears to be something to do with prototype. If I leave it as false, nothing shows up when rendered in the div. When I set to true, it spits out this broken HTML:
http://pastebin.com/cYGDHbih

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the collection form type, and the textarea is not showing, add:

```
'allow_add'    => true
```

to the properties array().
The code would look something like this:

```
->add(
'supportEntries',
'collection',
array(
    'type' => new SupportEntryType(),
    'label' => 'Support Entries',
    'error_bubbling' => true,
    'allow_add'    => true
    'cascade_validation' => true,
)
```

)

To show the widget, assuming you are using twig:

```
  {{ form_widget(form.supportEntries.vars.prototype.comment) }}
```

For saving the support entry, depending on how you built your entities, you might need to make some extra modifications.

The documentation should help you get it right:
[How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)