# How can I render this form collection field without using javascript?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a form field that is a collection of another entity. The goal is that when you create a ticket, it creates the initial entry which is setup as a onetomany relationship. When I set the collection to 'allow_add' and 'protoype' false, it renders an empty div. Pretty useless. If I set the collection to 'allow_add' and 'protoype' true, then it puts all of the contents of the form field in the data-protype attribute of the div.

For example:

```
<div class="form-group"><label>Support Entries</label><div id="form_supportEntries" data-prototype="    &lt;div class=&quot;form-group&quot;&gt;&lt;label class=&quot;required&quot;&gt;__name__label__&lt;/label&gt;&lt;div id=&quot;form_supportEntries___name__&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;form-group&quot;&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;form_supportEntries___name___comment&quot; class=&quot;required&quot;&gt;Comment&lt;/label&gt;&lt;textarea class=&quot;form-control&quot; id=&quot;form_supportEntries___name___comment&quot; name=&quot;form[supportEntries][__name__][comment]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot;&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"></div></div>
```

Then I have to use this javascript to display the form field:

```
    <script>
        var entryFieldHTML = $("#form_supportEntries").attr("data-prototype");
        $("#form_supportEntries").html(entryFieldHTML);
    </script>
```

Once I run that javascript, it displays and works as expected. But I don't really have a need for this data-prototype attribute in that you will only ever have one supportEntry on this form.

This question is related to: [Symfony form creates new object and create first one-to-many object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184785/symfony-form-creates-new-object-and-create-first-one-to-many-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Controller side, initialize the first SupportEntry :

```
// My controller, creating the form
$supportTicket = new SupportTicket();
$supportTicket->addSupportEntry(new SupportEntry); // It's the frst item of the collection
```

In your Twig file, render the only first item with ;

```
{{ form_row(form.supportEntries) }}
```

or better something like :

```
{{ form_row(form.supportEntries.children.0) }}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. This worked perfectly. The only issue now is that this is being created <label class="required">0</label> and I can't tell from where it comes from

Comment: to remove `<label class="required">0</label>` Use the `'entry_options' => ['label'=>false]` as parameter of field within your `$builder`

Answer (score 2):

You could revert to `'allow_add' => false` and then use this controller code snippet:

```
public function someControllerAction(){
    $entity = ...; 

    // It is vital for `supportEntities` property not to be NULL
    // Add new, blank, sub-entity, since you'll need only one
    $entity->getSupportEntries()->add(new SupportEntry());      

    $form = $this->createForm( new YourFormClass(), $entity);

    // REST OF THE LOGIC    
}
```

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If You only need one form field, You can render it in the template in the following way:

```
{{ form_widget(form.support_entries.vars.prototype)|replace({'__name__':1})|raw }}
```

This only works if neither `{{ form_widget(form.support_entries) }}` nor `{{ form_row(form.support_entries) }}` has been called previously.

This does not work, unfortunately, if You would like to render more then one form field from the same collection (which is what I need to do). This is because rendering a form field causes `FormView::setRendered()` to be called (via `FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock()`), which sets a flag, which is checked before rendering the same form field again.